# Merge more than two excel files into one

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine more than 2 excel files into a single file using python script. I have illustrated the usecase in the example below:

**INPUT**

```
file1.xlsx : has only one sheet i.e. Sheet1
file2.xlsx : has only one sheet i.e. Sheet2
file3.xlsx : has only one sheet i.e. Sheet3
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Combined_file.xlsx : It should have 3 sheets i.e. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3
```

I have come across various Python based solutions using `panda` module but all solutions were focussed to condense the information into a single sheet. However my requirement is to maintain the data in different sheets in the combined excel file.

Please share the right approach for this usecase. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

with pd.ExcelWriter('Combined_file.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

[pandas.ExcelWriter — pandas documentation](http://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

[pandas.DataFrame.to_excel - pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I will review the code and share my feedback.

Comment: Hi Zebartin, What is the `path_to_file.xlsx` in your code? Is it the absolute path of the output file or the directory where the input files are present? Also, What are `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` variables? Are these the the absolute path of the input files?

Comment: The `path_to_file.xlsx` is the path where you wish to put your output file, in your case, let's change it to `Combined_file.xlsx`.

Then `df1` and `df2` are input dataframes which you read from input files. Maybe I should edit the answer to clarify them. `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are sheet names you'd like to have. @Yash

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


output_file = 'fileout_'+ str(sys.argv[1]) +'.xlsx'
all_workbooks = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_file, '*.xlsx'))
all_df = []
for workbook in all_workbooks:
    all_worksheets = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheetname='Output',    index_col=None)
    for worksheet, data in all_worksheets.items():
        all_df.append(data)
data_concatenated = pd.concat(all_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
data_concatenated.to_excel(writer, sheetname='concatenated_Output',  index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).